# While indexing large data, if I delete the index ElasticSearch creating index again and indexing the docs instead of giving Index not exists

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am indexing the large data in batches of 1000. I have 100000 docs. Inbetween if I delete the index from the elastic search directly(from : http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/) it is recreating the index and indexing the new docs so old docs is lost. I need to through error if index in not existing.
Below is the json query for two records(it will be 1000 in real)

```
{ "index" :  {"_index":"1020","_type":"PROGRAMS","_id":"3149012","_routing":"PROGRAMS"} }
{
  "OBJID": 3149015,
  "MAINTITLE": "SPEAR TALK",
  "A_S_DESC": null,
  "A_S_ORIG_NA": "PFT",
  "EPISODE_NAME": "DEMOPROG",
  "A_S_DURATION": null,
  "A_S_EP_NU": "111",
  "A_S_EP_NA": "DEMOPROG",
  "S_SOM": "10:00:00:00",
  "S_FRAMERAT": 25,
  "A_S_QUALITY": "HD",
  "A_S_TX_TIME": "150200",
  "A_S_TX_DATE": "20150228",
  "TX_DATE_TIME": "20150228150200",
  "REGISTRATION": "20150228",
  "REGISTRATIO2": "150240",
  "REGISTRATION_DATE_TIME": "20150228150240",
  "CreatedOn": "2015-02-28T15:02:40",
  "A_S_VERSION": "MIX",
  "SUG_MAINTITLE": "DEMO PROGRAM 1 EP 111",
  "A_DISPLAY_NA": "DEMO PROGRAM 1",
  "channel": "DEMO-CHANNEL1",
  "CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NA": "DEMO CHANNEL 1",
  "IS_ARCHIVED": "NOT ARCHIVED",
  "IS_TXRC": "TX",
  "OBJECTCLASS": "PROGRAMS",
  "SUB_OBJECTCLASS_FACET": "Assets",
  "OBJECTCLASS_FACET": "Programs",
  "kxjrt94fbr": "kxjrt94fbr",
  "SortOrderValue": "1",
  "VideoURL": null,
  "ThumbURL": null,
  "GENRE": null,
  "S_ArchivedInstanceInfo": null,
  "searchColumn": "SPEAR TALK DEMOPROG DEMO PROGRAM 1",
  "RowNum": 2
}
{ "index" :  {"_index":"1020","_type":"PROGRAMS","_id":"3149015","_routing":"PROGRAMS"} }
{
  "OBJID": 3149015,
  "MAINTITLE": "SPEAR TALK",
  "A_S_DESC": null,
  "A_S_ORIG_NA": "PFT",
  "EPISODE_NAME": "DEMOPROG",
  "A_S_DURATION": null,
  "A_S_EP_NU": "111",
  "A_S_EP_NA": "DEMOPROG",
  "S_SOM": "10:00:00:00",
  "S_FRAMERAT": 25,
  "A_S_QUALITY": "HD",
  "A_S_TX_TIME": "150200",
  "A_S_TX_DATE": "20150228",
  "TX_DATE_TIME": "20150228150200",
  "REGISTRATION": "20150228",
  "REGISTRATIO2": "150240",
  "REGISTRATION_DATE_TIME": "20150228150240",
  "CreatedOn": "2015-02-28T15:02:40",
  "A_S_VERSION": "MIX",
  "SUG_MAINTITLE": "DEMO PROGRAM 1 EP 111",
  "A_DISPLAY_NA": "DEMO PROGRAM 1",
  "channel": "DEMO-CHANNEL1",
  "CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NA": "DEMO CHANNEL 1",
  "IS_ARCHIVED": "NOT ARCHIVED",
  "IS_TXRC": "TX",
  "OBJECTCLASS": "PROGRAMS",
  "SUB_OBJECTCLASS_FACET": "Assets",
  "OBJECTCLASS_FACET": "Programs",
  "kxjrt94fbr": "kxjrt94fbr",
  "SortOrderValue": "1",
  "VideoURL": null,
  "ThumbURL": null,
  "GENRE": null,
  "S_ArchivedInstanceInfo": null,
  "searchColumn": "SPEAR TALK DEMOPROG DEMO PROGRAM 1",
  "RowNum": 2
}
```

Next 1000 batch will be indexed in the same way. Do I need to check whether Index present or not? or is there any way to know from ElasticSearch?

Comment: Can I ask why you would delete your index in the middle of a bulk upload task?

Comment: I was indexing large data(which can take 5 hours of time), but data mismatch was the problem for me which we realised later. So I deleted by assuming it will stop. But it is creating index and docs without interrupt.

Comment: Yes it will do that by default. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch will create an index automatically based on the structure of your object, but bear in mind that any customised field settings may not be maintained this way.

If you want to check whether an index exists or not, use:

```
curl -XHEAD -i 'http://localhost:9200/your_index'
```

or the equivalent from whichever client you are using.

If you want to stop automatic index creation, Add this to config/elasticsearch.yml:

```
action.auto_create_index: false
```

As can be found here: [Automatic index creation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation)

Comment: action.auto_create_index: 0 
setting I did but its not helping me. still samething.

Comment: apologies - this has been updated to false rather than 0 - updated my answer again.

Comment: Is adding this to yml file is enough or do I need to make any code changes? Because if I make false also same issue.

Comment: have you restarted your elasticsearch cluster after making changes to the .yml?

Comment: Thumbs up.. Great. I restarted the elasticsearch service. Now issue is solved. Thanks a lot.